# Property [bank] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\booking\resources\views\client\payment\make_payment.blade.php)

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get all the bank details in my database that are current.

I have tried using this code

```
     $settings=Setting::where(['is_current' => 1])->get();
```

But it give me the error above.

I did some reserach and the answers I got told me to add first to my code as follows

```
    $settings=Setting::where(['is_current' => 1])->first();
```

But that only returns one column( the first column that meets the supplied condition)

when I try to dump the output of the fist code (using get()) I get this

[image: The output of dd($settings) on the first code using get()]

and when I try to dump the output of the second code( using first()) this is what I get
[image: The output of dd($settings on the first code using first()]

This is the code on my view

```
    @foreach($settings as $setting)
                        @if($settings->bank == 'Mpesa')
                        <li class="text-black text-center">{{ $setting->bank }}<br>
                            Paybill No: {{ $setting->account_no }} <br>
                            Account no: {{ $setting->branch }} <br></li>
                        @endif
                        <li class="text-black text-center">our {{ $setting->bank }} bank account<br>
                            Account No: {{ $setting->account_no }} <br>
                            Account Name: {{ $setting->name }} <br>
                            Branch: {{ $setting->branch }} <br></li>
                        @endforeach
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `->get()` and then you need to change

```
@if($settings->bank == 'Mpesa')
```

to

```
@if($setting->bank == 'Mpesa')
```

in your view file.

Also add an `@else` clause to the other list of the `@if...@endif` statement

```
<ol class="text-black text-center">
    @foreach($settings as $setting)
        @if($setting->bank == 'Mpesa')
        <li class="text-black text-center">{{ $setting->bank }}<br>
            Paybill No: {{ $setting->account_no }} <br>
            Account no: {{ $setting->branch }} <br>
        </li>
        @else
        <li class="text-black text-center">our {{ $setting->bank }} bank account<br>
            Account No: {{ $setting->account_no }} <br>
            Account Name: {{ $setting->name }} <br>
            Branch: {{ $setting->branch }} <br>
        </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ol>
```

Comment: That prints out the Mpesa twice  both under the condition and the the foreach loop. Is that avoidable?

Comment: that still does the same though I have solved it by adding ```@else``` to handle the other part I have also updated your answer to help any other person with the same problem .Thanks